# Deploying maven build project on tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin

I have been trying to configure maven to one of the existing projects. I have performed these steps:

1. Install m2e plugin for maven
2. Add dependencies in the pom.xml : It only has dependencies - no plugins added
3. No errors found
4. Started Tomcat Server 7 - started successfully.
5. Now when I try to add the project on the server -> i.e. I have run maven clean install and then the jar is created. I then go to the server and right click Add and Remove projects - > Nothing happens
6. When trying to access the project link using //localhost:8080/projectName, I get the message "The requested resource is not available"

Can anyone please suggest what am i missing? Do i need any plugin  for the tomcat server? Or any plugin to be added on my pom.xml?

Thanks a lot for the help

Adding the pom.xml below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
<groupId>com</groupId> 
<artifactId>abc</artifactId> 
<version>1.0</version> 
<packaging>jar</packaging> 
<name>ABC</name> 
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url> 

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId> 
        <version>2.5.6</version> 
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: explain this _Now when I try to add the project on the server - Nothing happens_

Comment: how can your deployed app work if you don't have any plugins in your pom.xml file to create either a .war or .jar file. upload you pom.xml above

Comment: @lakshman: I have updated my initial post to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

> i.e. I have run maven clean install and then the **jar** is created. I
>   then go to the server and right click Add and Remove projects

You should create a war, not a jar.

Take a look at this:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. But I have a slightly different project structure and the web.xml is in **web->WEB_INF->web.xml** in place of **webapp->WEB_INF->web.xml**. I dont want to change the structure since its existing project. Is there any way to configure this? If i make packaging to **war**, it doesnt find web.xml when i run maven for **clean install**

Comment: No matter you project structure, you won't be able to deploy a jar in Tomcat.

Comment: I have changed packaging to war, but maven is not able to find my web.xml. It gives this error: **Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)**

Comment: Create a new project with a war archetype and transfer your classes and static files.

Comment: That did work to some extent, although i am facing some other issues. Thanks for your pointer. Will update this issue once everything is sorted out. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, the war file generated now gets deployed onto tomcat server when its manually deployed. But doesn't work when deployed directly on the tomcat server through eclipse. Any specific step needs to be taken to do it on eclipse?